# find user name through full name / gecos field?

Tags: search, ldap, nsswitch, getent

Given a system where the user data comes from e.g. an OpenLDAP database and is not in the `/etc/passwd` file.
Is it possible to search through the `getent passwd` database and look up the user id/name by specifying (a part of) the full name?

E.g. `getent passwd newbie` gives me the following entry

```
newbie:x:1000:1000:firstname lastname:/home/newbie:/bin/zsh
```

How can I find all users with "lastname"? Is there something like [`getpwnam`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getpwnam.3.html) for the gecos field?

Note: I can not use just `getent passwd` (with no username) and then parse that since my database is too big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found a way to search the database, but looking up entries in OpenLDAP directly works for me.

```
$ ldapsearch -x -h ldap.example.com -ZZ \
             -D cn=lookup,dc=example,dc=com -W \
             -b ou=People,dc=example,dc=com -LLL \
             sn=lastname uid
dn: uid=newbie,ou=People,dc=example,dc=com  
uid: newbie

$
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like the following `sed` command:

```
$ SURNAME=Smith
$ getent passwd | sed -n '/'$SURNAME'/s/^\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\):\([[:alpha:]]\+ '$SURNAME'\):\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\)$/\1 (\5)/p'
$ fps (Finnbarr Smith)
  jms (James Smith)
$
```

The above 'sed` regex assumes that the GECOS field contains exactly <FIRSTNAME><SPACE><LASTNAME>, e.g. "James Smith", as per your question.  It can easily be modified to accommodate other GECOS field layouts.

Comment: The user mentioned in another comment that they were unable to use `getent passwd` since the database was too big.

Comment: @Kusalananda.  Ah, the user added that comment after I read their question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use awk on the output of `getent passwd`:

```
getent passwd | awk -F: '$5 ~ /lastname/ {print $1}'
```

Comment: oh, i should have clarified that the database is too large to output everything with `getent passwd`

Comment: Oh, I see. In that case you'll have to use database-specific tools (like you already are).